# access photos from Picasa in Android using Google APIs

Tags: android, picasa, google-api-java-client

I am trying to fetch photos from a Picasa album in Android.

I have used following link as a reference:

> http://gdata-java-client.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.2.1-alpha/sample/picasa/picasa-atom-android-sample/instructions.html

But in the above example I think the user can only access **albums**, whereas I want to access photos also, which might need PhotoEntry Class, so can anyone suggest to me what files I need for Android previously to get photos from Picasa?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this source code for a widget that uses picasa api.  It uses the older gdata api libraries.  I have been unable to get the new libraries to work for downloading.

http://droidphotoframe.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/droidphotoframe/trunk/